# acts_as_taggable_on: NoMethodError: undefined method `add'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm attempting to use the acts_as_taggable gem in my Rails project, and I don't know if someone can point out what I'm doing wrong or if there is a bug in the project.

I've filed an issue with the project: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/issues/688 though no one has responded yet.

I cannot use the basic functionality of adding tags using e.g: `taglist.add("a")` or `taglist.remove("a)` or set tags using `taglist = 'a'` , etc. The methods don't appear to exist.

I am using Ruby 2.2.3 and Rails 4.2.3. My gemfile has:

`gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.4'`
I've also tried

`gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.5'`
In my model I have:

```
class Space < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :skills
```

from the rails console I can do the following:

```
> s = Space.first
 => #<Space id: 1172, created_at: "2015-09-24 08:13:09", ...<many fields>... updated_at: "2015-09-24 08:13:09"> 

> s.skills
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = $1 AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = $2 AND "taggings"."context" = $3  [["taggable_id", 1172], ["taggable_type", "Space"], ["context", "skills"]]
```

=> #

```
> s.skills.add("a")
NoMethodError: undefined method `add' for #     <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
from (irb):3
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/n/code/pop/poprails/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /Users/n/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@poprails/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/n/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/n/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.3 :004
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
> s = Space.first
 => #<Space id: 1172, created_at: "2015-09-24 08:13:09", ...<many fields>... updated_at: "2015-09-24 08:13:09"> 

> s.skill_list.add("a")
```

or by comma

```
> s.skill_list.add("a,b,n,m)
```

Then

> s.skill_list

it will return array of

```
  ["a","b","n","m"]
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
s.skills.where(name: "a").first_or_create
```

or

```
s.skill_list.add("a")
```